# Module '"angular2-csv"' has no exported member 'Angular2Csv'.ts(2305)

Tags: angular, angular15

I am trying to use Anguar2csv package in my angular 15 application. I have a export service where I have imported it:

```
import { Angular2Csv } from 'angular2-csv';
```

This service is provided in my shared module. And in that shared module I have kept the Angular2CsvModule also in imports array. But the error occurs when I am compiling the code. Please help how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

anguar2-csv was originally build for angular 6 and no longer work with Ivy compiled applications.
try using this fork instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/export-to-csv
it extracted the functionality and removed the angular related part